SQLAlchemy Error: Table 'user' is already defined for this MetaData instance. How to resolve
I'm a beginner in Flask and SQLAlchemy. I encountered an issue after deleting a database in MySQL and rerunning my models. Previously, everything worked fine, but now I get this error:
D:\Nam 3\CNPM\hahahaha_clinic\.venv\Scripts\python.exe" "D:\Nam 3\CNPM\hahahaha_clinic\clinic\models.py" 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Nam 3\CNPM\hahahaha_clinic\clinic\models.py", line 20, in <module>
    class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
  File "D:\Nam 3\CNPM\hahahaha_clinic\.venv\Lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\model.py", line 92, in __init__
    super().__init__(name, bases, d, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Nam 3\CNPM\hahahaha_clinic\.venv\Lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\model.py", line 144, in __init__
    super().__init__(name, bases, d, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Nam 3\CNPM\hahahaha_clinic\.venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\decl_api.py", line 196, in __init__
    _as_declarative(reg, cls, dict_)
  File "D:\Nam 3\CNPM\hahahaha_clinic\.venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\decl_base.py", line 244, in _as_declarative
    return _MapperConfig.setup_mapping(registry, cls, dict_, None, {})
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\Nam 3\CNPM\hahahaha_clinic\.venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\decl_base.py", line 325, in setup_mapping
    return _ClassScanMapperConfig(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\Nam 3\CNPM\hahahaha_clinic\.venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\decl_base.py", line 576, in __init__
    self._setup_table(table)
  File "D:\Nam 3\CNPM\hahahaha_clinic\.venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\decl_base.py", line 1759, in _setup_table
    table_cls(
  File "D:\Nam 3\CNPM\hahahaha_clinic\.venv\Lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\model.py", line 171, in __table_cls__
    return sa.Table(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<string>", line 2, in __new__
  File "D:\Nam 3\CNPM\hahahaha_clinic\.venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\deprecations.py", line 281, in warned
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)  # type: ignore[no-any-return]
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\Nam 3\CNPM\hahahaha_clinic\.venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\schema.py", line 427, in __new__
    return cls._new(*args, **kw)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\Nam 3\CNPM\hahahaha_clinic\.venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\schema.py", line 459, in _new
    raise exc.InvalidRequestError(
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Table 'user' is already defined for this MetaData instance.  Specify 'extend_existing=True' to redefine options and columns on an existing Table object.

Process finished with exit code 1

This is my models.py:
from enum import Enum as UserEnum
from sqlalchemy import DateTime, Enum, Column, Integer, String, Float, Boolean, ForeignKey, Date, func, Time
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from clinic import app, db, dao, utils
from datetime import datetime, date
from flask_login import UserMixin
from itsdangerous.url_safe import URLSafeSerializer as Serializer


class UserRole(UserEnum):
    ADMIN = 'admin'
    PATIENT = 'patient'
    NURSE = 'nurse'


class Gender(UserEnum):
    MALE = 'male'
    FEMALE = 'female'

class User(db.Model, UserMixin):

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = Column(String(50), nullable=False)
    username = Column(String(50), nullable=False, unique=True)
    password = Column(String(70), nullable=False)
    avatar = Column(String(255))
    email = Column(String(50))
    user_role = Column(Enum(UserRole), nullable=False)
    gender = Column(Enum(Gender))
    phone = Column(String(20), nullable=True)
    address = Column(String(255), default='HoChiMinh')
    dob = Column(Date, default=date.today)

    def get_token(self):
        serial=Serializer(app.secret_key)
        return serial.dumps({'user_id':self.id})

    @staticmethod
    def verify_token(token):
        serial = Serializer(app.secret_key)
        try:
            user_id = serial.loads(token)['user_id']
        except:
            return None
        return User.query.get(user_id)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Admin(db.Model):
    id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(User.id), primary_key=True)

class Patient(db.Model):
    id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(User.id), primary_key=True)
    appointments = relationship('Appointment', backref='patient', lazy=True)

class Nurse(db.Model):
    id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(User.id), primary_key=True)
    appointmentLists = relationship('AppointmentList', backref='nurse', lazy=True)

class BaseModel(db.Model):
    __abstract__ = True
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    create_date = Column(DateTime, default=func.now())
    update_date = Column(DateTime, default=func.now(), onupdate=func.now())

class AppointmentList(BaseModel):
    schedule_date = Column(Date, unique=True)
    nurse_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(Nurse.id), nullable=False)
    appointments = relationship('Appointment', backref='appointment_list', lazy=True)

class Status(UserEnum):
    PENDING = 'pending'
    CONFIRMED = 'confirmed'
    CANCELED = 'canceled' 
    COMPLETED = 'completed'

class Appointment(BaseModel):
    description = Column(String(255), nullable=False)
    status = Column(Enum(Status), default=Status.PENDING)
    schedule_date = Column(Date, nullable=False)
    schedule_time = Column(Time, nullable=False )
    patient_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(Patient.id), nullable=False)
    appointment_list_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(AppointmentList.id), nullable=True)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    with app.app_context():
         db.create_all() 
         db.session.commit()


While this works, I still don’t understand why this issue happens or how SQLAlchemy knows about the table even after the database was deleted.
Are there better ways to handle this issue without using extend_existing?
Where is SQLAlchemy storing the metadata about the existing tables, and how can I reset or clear it?
I’d appreciate any guidance or suggestions. Thank you!

You might have to have UserMixin before db.Model when inheriting from multiple parents so that the resolution sequence works as expected.
